# Keep on getting error when trying to get RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have this view

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <RelativeLayout ...>
```

I define the RelativeLayout, one that I want to manipulate in Java, like this

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.rltv_layout);
```

I want to change the Relative's height, so I figured I'd use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
lpp.height = lpp.height + someHeights;
parent.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Then error happened, LogCat said

```
05-18 14:01:49.829: E/AndroidRuntime(12856): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast 
to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

So I changed it to

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lpp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
```

Then error happened, LogCat said

```
05-18 14:06:16.297: E/AndroidRuntime(13183): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast 
to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

So what is it that it wants?

Also, AFAIK, LayoutParams type depended on its parent's type, not the View itself. At one point I tried `ScrollView.LayoutParams` and still got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only using `lpp.height`, using `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` directly would suffice. No casting needed.

Like you said, the LayoutParams depend on the parent view. But `ScrollView` doesn't define its own subclass. That's why you find `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

For the second cast issue, you might have set the `LayoutParams` to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with `parent.setLayoutParams(lp)`.